# Beautiful Soup not showing correct urls

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on this URL: https://www.sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261&load_ajax=1&page=0&company_name=&meeting_type=&from_date=&to_date=

I wanted to extract all the .pdf links from it. When I open it using BeautifulSoup, all the links are cut whereas I can see the links perfectly when I use the command `urllib.request.urlopen(url)`

Could someone please help me to retrieve those .pdf links?

```
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261&load_ajax=1&page=0&company_name=&meeting_type=&from_date=&to_date=').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand,'lxml')
```

Comment: Why not scrap directly from https://www.sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261?

Comment: Wouldnt it be hard to work on ajax data?how would I do it for all 261 tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your page actually gives json, not html. Therefore, there's some escaping included in `fhand` and parsing that gives nonsense. What you actually want is the message field of `fhand`. This should work:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261&load_ajax=1&page=0&company_name=&meeting_type=&from_date=&to_date=').read()

HTML = json.loads(fhand)['message']
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for a_tag in a_tags:
    url = a_tag['href']
    if '.pdf' in url:
        print(url)
```

Note: I suggest you use the requests package instead of urllib.

Comment: I tried all the parsers ,its just that jujst before pasting the code I gave a last attempt by not using parser and copied that code. The '.pdf' you get are not concrete urls on the other hand fhand gives the complete url

Comment: Can you please provide the full code? I have another idea what's causing the problem.

Comment: if this is the code  `soup.findAll('a')[0].get('href')` I get -  \"https:\/\/portal.sesgovernance.com\/proxy_reports\/0925183203Asahi 

where as I should  get 
https:\\/\\/portal.sesgovernance.com\\/proxy_reports\\/0925183203Asahi India Glass Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf

Comment: I think the problem is that you directly pass in `fhand` to the soup which is json and not html, but `BeautifulSoup` expects html. Sadly, it does not tell you that in this step... I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks man!.But how could you tell that the url is json?Noob here

Comment: Looking at the html of the page (Ctrl+U in Chrome) shows something like `{"key": "value", "another_key": "another value"}` which is typical to JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

a) You could parse the json response.

b) Use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to directly scrape [sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261](http://sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261).

Also a gentle reminder to avoid using `urllib.request.urlopen` as it is deprecated. Use [Requests](https://html.python-requests.org/) as suggested [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

req = requests.get('https://www.sesgovernance.com/archived-reports?tpages=261&load_ajax=1&page=0&company_name=&meeting_type=&from_date=&to_date=')
req.raise_for_status()
resp = json.loads(req.text)['message']
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
pdf_list = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'pdf'))
print(pdf_list)
```

Output:

```
[<a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/0925183203Asahi India Glass Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3020518587Sobha Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/2151608573Avanti Feeds Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3017832951AU Small Finance Bank Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/8183831859Mahindra &amp; Mahindra Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3259351215Wonderla Holidays Ltd._SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/0451115532Hawkins Cooker Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_07 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3995521831ISGEC Heavy Engineering  Ltd._SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3156275331Kalpataru Power Transmission Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/1356756312Adani Enterprises Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/5612331522Adani Transmission Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3515944823Mphasis Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/5953271399Bombay Dyeing &amp; Manufacturing Company Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/3455819426TVS Motor Company Ltd_SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>, <a class="view-btn" href="https://portal.sesgovernance.com/proxy_reports/0355221651SRF Ltd._SES Proxy Advisory Report_AGM_7 August 2018.pdf" target="_blank">View</a>]
```